# First section in UITableView never has the correct content

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that never works properly. This table view has 2 sections.

I have created 2 UIButtons, they both are practically the same image, but one is grey and one is red.

Every row in the UITableView is supposed to have the grey button when the UITableView first loads, and then if a user taps the row's button then it switches to the red version of the button.

For some reason, when I load the view controller with this UITableView on my iPhone, the rows in the first section will never have the button. What's weird is if I tap my finger where the button is supposed to be 2 things happen:

1. The functionality attached to the button works and NSLogs in the console in xcode.
2. The red button appears.

So it's like the grey button is there, it's just invisible. This doesn't work because if a user sees rows without a button they are going to think something is broken or that they can't tap on that row.

Also, if I scroll to the very bottom of my UITableView, and then scroll back up again, the invisible grey buttons will magically appear like they were there the whole time.

What's funny, is the textLabel and detailTextLabel are always visible and always correct for this first section, but for some reason the button just never wants to work correctly.

Here are the first 3 method implementations that are involved in creating my UITableView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 2 ;

}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


if(section == 0)

    return [self.potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray count];

if(section == 1)

    return [self.potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray count];

else return 0;



}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 if(section == 0)
    return @"Friends Using The App";

 if(section == 1)
    return @"Send to Contact";

 else return @"nil";

}
```

And then here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method implementation which does most of the work in creating the UITableView and which actually creates the UIButton settings for each row. The if else statement really has 2 sets of nearly identical code, the only difference is one is for section 1 of the table view and the other is for section 2:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";


 UITableViewCell  *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


  if (indexPath.section == 0) {



   NSString *firstNameForTableView = [self.potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


   PFUser *user = [self.allUsersInParse objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    UIImage *addUserButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal-g"];
    UIImage *addUserButtonImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal"];



    UIButton *addUserButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];

    addUserButton.frame = CGRectMake(237, -10, 64, 64);



[addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateSelected];



[addUserButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



addUserButton.tag = indexPath.row;



[cell.textLabel setText:firstNameForTableView];

[cell.detailTextLabel setText:user.username];

[cell.contentView addSubview:addUserButton];



} else {



NSString *firstNameForTableView2 = [self.potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


NSString *userNameForTableView2 = [self.potentiaFriendsPhoneNumberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



UIImage *addFriendButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal-G"];
UIImage *addFriendButtonImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal"];


UIButton *addFriendButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];


addFriendButton.frame = CGRectMake(237, -10, 64, 64);



  [addFriendButton setImage:addFriendButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  [addFriendButton setImage:addFriendButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

  [addFriendButton setImage:addFriendButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateSelected];



[addFriendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInsideForNonUsers:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



addFriendButton.tag = indexPath.row;



[cell.textLabel setText:firstNameForTableView2];

[cell.detailTextLabel setText:userNameForTableView2];

[cell.contentView addSubview:addFriendButton];



    }


  return cell;

}
```

This is literally driving me insane and I have been trying to figure this out for the past 9 hours and cannot figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: You have a really big problem here... Every time you dequeue a reusable cell, you're adding a subview (the button) to it.  Do you ever remove the subview?  So if a user scrolls up and down a few times you will have more and more subviews added to the cells, and your performance will degrade...

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing more about this. Would you like me to ask another question about it so you can answer, or would you be willing to please add an answer to this question with some addition instructions or code. Thanks.

Comment: Just NSLog your UITableViewCell's subviews at the end of cellForRowAtIndexPath and watch your console as you scroll up and down.  `NSLog(@"Cell subviews: %@", cell.contentView.subviews);`

Comment: Ok I think I understand. So what can I do to fix this issue? I'm new to objective-c and not sure how to solve this problem. If you want, I can ask a new question and link you to it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Essentially you'll want to use view tags to make sure whether there is already a subview before you add a new one..  Check the Apple Documentation here for more info - it covers both Storyboard cells and programatically created cells: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image name is case sensitive, `addUserButtonImage` is "SliderThumb-Normal-**g**" in your first section while it is "SliderThumb-Normal-**G**" in second section!

Comment: You know what's really sad, is the image names were correct this morning and the table view was doing the error i described, so implemented a massive change to my code to fix the problem. Turns out the fix worked, but somehow the g was wrong after the fix. THANK YOU. I don't know whether to be happy or cry.

Comment: Cheers bro, i am pretty sure you are mastering UITableView :D.

Comment: LOL more like mastering failure.